# How to put a ColorPicker positioned by a gridPane on top of a Canvas

Tags: java, user-interface, canvas, javafx, gridpane

I got 3 Color pickers that are positioned using a grid pane, I'm also using a canvas. But The problem is, the canvas pushes the grid pane to the bottom of the screen. So if im using `root.add(HeadColor, 0, 1);` (to add the first colorpicker to the grid pane on column 0 and row 1) The Colorpicker positions itself somewhere in the middle of the screen because the grid pane starts below the grid pane. So my question is, how can I position the grid pane on top of the canvas, or the colorpicker on top of the canvas?

The code that I use :

```
package gui;

import display.Image;
import java.awt.Button;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.util.logging.*;
import javafx.application.Application;
import javafx.event.*;
import javafx.geometry.*;
import javafx.scene.Scene;
import javafx.scene.canvas.*;
import javafx.scene.control.ColorPicker;
import javafx.scene.layout.*;
import javafx.scene.layout.VBox;
import javafx.scene.paint.*;
import javafx.scene.text.Font;
import javafx.stage.Stage;

public class JavaFXColorPicker extends Application {
private Image head;
private Image heart;

ColorPicker HeadColor = new ColorPicker();
ColorPicker BodyColor = new ColorPicker();
ColorPicker LegColor = new ColorPicker();

@Override
public void start(Stage primaryStage) throws IOException {

    GridPane root = new GridPane();
    final Canvas canvas = new Canvas(200,300);

    Scene scene = new Scene(root, 500, 400, Color.BLACK);   
    GraphicsContext gc = canvas.getGraphicsContext2D();
    root.setHgap(10);
    root.setVgap(10);
    root.setPadding(new Insets(10, 30, 30, 30));

    HeadColor.setOnAction(new EventHandler(){ 
        @Override
        public void handle(Event event) {
            Color HeadPaint = HeadColor.getValue();
            Color[] HeadColorArray = new Color[]
                {
                    new Color(0 , 0, 0, 1),
                    HeadPaint,
                    HeadPaint,
                    HeadPaint,
                    HeadPaint,
                    new Color(1, 1, 1, 1) // de ogen
                 };

            try {
                head = new display.Image(display.Parts.playerHead);
            } catch (IOException ex) {
                Logger.getLogger(JavaFXColorPicker.class.getName())
                        .log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
            }

            head.recolour(HeadColorArray);
            Image i = head;
            gc.drawImage(i.show(), 200, 100);
        }
    });

    root.getChildren().add(canvas);
    root.add(HeadColor, 0, 1); 
    root.add(BodyColor, 0, 2); 
    root.add(LegColor,0,3);

    primaryStage.setTitle("Customize Character!");
    primaryStage.setScene(scene);
    primaryStage.show();
}

public static void main(String[] args) {
    launch(args);
}
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem is this:

```
root.getChildren().add(canvas);
```

The [GridPane documentation](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/api/javafx/scene/layout/GridPane.html) states:

> If the row/column indices are not explicitly set, then the child will be placed in the first row/column.

Assign a row and column to your Canvas, just as you are doing with your ColorPickers.

Comment: To what row did you add the Canvas?

Comment: If you want the Canvas to be below the ColorPickers, perhaps you should place it in a higher row than any of the ColorPickers are using.